# Laravel Flash Message Not Showing on Password Reset

Tags: laravel-8

I am trying to output the message returned when sending a password reset email using laravel password reset. I get the correct message of `email has been sent!` but on the redirect back the flash message doesn't show. I do see the successful save to the `password_resets_table`.

Controller returning back after successful email

```
    return $status === Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
            ? back()->with(['status' => __($status)])
            : back()->withErrors(['Email' => __($status)]);
```

Blade file that it gets redirected back to checking for status

```
     @if(!empty($status))
        <div class="alert alert-success"> {{ $status }}</div>
    @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering My Own Question:

The code I posted above was valid but the issue was in my route I had a `Route::group([])` and in there I had the `guest` middleware but also had to add `web` middleware for the laravel session to work. Once I added the `web` middleware I was able to see my flash messages.

Working Route Group

```
    Route::group(
    [
        'middleware' => ['guest', 'web'],
        'namespace' => 'app\Http',
    ]...
```